# error: unterminated character set at position 0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, regex, dataframe

I'm trying to remove a list of rare_words from a column of a pandas dataframe. I wrote the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import regex as re
    
for word in rare_words:
        df['tweet_text'] = df['tweet_text'].str.replace(word, '')
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
error: unterminated character set at position 0
```

Comment: Are you actually using regex, or can you use `regex=False` in `replace()`?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `try` block with a `print()` in the `except` clause, to see which word is causing the error?

Comment: It seems like one of your words in `rare_words` contains some non escaped braces, which has a special meaning in regex. Check for one of `[ ] ( ) { }` .

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example ?

Comment: @Psidom I have set regex=False in replace(). It's running now but taking long time to complete bcoz the dataset is very big. I'll let u know once the code finishes running.

Comment: But is there any kind of bracket in `rare_words`, which is a list of words, not your large dataframe?

Comment: @Joe yes, at least one such rare words --> [niyaaz', 'offering]

Comment: ok, so I believe that would throw that error.  Did `regex=False` run without error?

Comment: @Joe yes.......